# Android: Declaring UI elements in a different class

Tags: java, android, class, user-interface, extends

I have my main class that extends Activity and it's over 2k line so I'm trying to write the code in a different class but not sure what it should extend. I've declared a Context and sent it the context from my main class but when I try something like `context.findViewById()` it won't let me.

What is the best practice here?

```
    public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    //somewhere in a method, in an onClickListener
    new Profile(getApplicationContext()).userCreate();
    }

public class Profile{

    Context ctx;
    int userID;

    public Profile (Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    public void userCreate(){
        Button create = (Button) ctx.findViewById()// can't call find view
    }
}
```

Comment: We cannot know what you're talking about if you don't post the code of the class in question.

Comment: First of all don't prefix your question titles with tag words like Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough. Secondly, either pass the activity reference directly to `Profile`(so the Profile constructor will be public `Profile(Activity context)`) or cast the context parameter to an Activity(but you need to pass the activity reference and not the application context) and then use the `findViewById()` method.

Comment: how do I get the activity reference?

Comment: *how do I get the activity reference?* - Simple pass `this` when creating the Profile instance in the `HomeScreen` activity `new Profile(this)...`. Note: this must be done from a non static method,  from the `onCreate()` onwards.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot; I passed MyClass.this since I'm in an OnClickListener